# Why is performance of executing Mockito mocks so erratic?

Tags: java, performance, mockito

Would anyone have an explanation, or even better a suggested fix, for why the time taken to execute Mockito mocks is so erratic?  The simplest SSCCE I could come up with for this is below:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

public class TestSimpleMockTiming
{
    public static final void main (final String args [])
    {
        final Runnable theMock = mock (Runnable.class);

        int tookShort = 0;
        int tookMedium = 0;
        int tookLong = 0;
        int tookRidiculouslyLong = 0;
        long longest = 0;

        for (int n = 0; n < 2000000; n++)
        {
            final long startTime = System.nanoTime ();
            theMock.run ();
            final long duration = System.nanoTime () - startTime;

            if (duration < 1000000)                 // 0.001 seconds
                tookShort++;
            else if (duration < 100000000)      // 0.1 seconds
                tookMedium++;
            else if (duration < 1000000000)     // 1 second !!!
                tookLong++;
            else
                tookRidiculouslyLong++;

            longest = Math.max (longest, duration);
        }

        System.out.println (tookShort + ", " + tookMedium + ", " + tookLong + ", " + tookRidiculouslyLong);
        System.out.println ("Longest duration was " + longest + " ns");
    }
}
```

If I run this (from within Eclipse, using JDK 1.7.45 on Win 7 x64) typical output looks like:

```
1999983, 4, 9, 4
Longest duration was 5227445252 ns
```

So, while in the majority of situations the mock executes very fast, there's several executions that take even longer than 1 second.  That's an eternity for a method that does nothing.  From my experimenting with this, I don't believe the issue is the accuracy of System.nanoTime (), I think the mock really does take that long to execute.  Is there anything I can do to improve on this and make the timing behave more consistently?

(FYI, why this is an issue is that I have a Swing app which contains various frames, and I try to write JUnit tests for the frames so that I can test that the layoutManagers behave correctly without having to fire up the whole app and navigate to the correct screen.  In one such test, the screen uses a javax.swing.Timer to implement scrolling, so the display will pan around an area when the mouse is held near the end of the frame.  I noticed the behaviour of this was very erratic, and the scrolling while usually fine would periodically freeze for up to a second and it looked dreadful.  I wrote an SSCCE around this, thinking the problem was that Swing Timers can't be depended on to fire at a consistent rate, and in the SSCCE it worked perfectly.

After hours of tearing my hair out then trying to spot differences between my real code and the scrolling demo SSCCE, I started putting nano timers around blocks of code that ran repeatedly, noticed the time taken by my paintComponent method to be very erratic and eventually narrowed it down to a mock call.  Testing the screen from running the real app, the scrolling behaves smoothly, its only a problem from the JUnit test because of the mock call, which led to me testing a simple mock in isolation with the SSCCE posted above.)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This test is flawed in multiple ways. If you want to benchmark properly I strongly suggest that using [**JMH**](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), it is done by someone **Alexey Shipilev** that is much smarter than us and definitely more knowledgeable on the JVM than most people doing Java on our beloved planet.

Here's the most notable way the test is flawed.

1. The test ignores what the JVM is doing, like the warmup phase, compilation C1 and C2 thread, GC, threading issues (even though this code is not multi-threaded, the JVM/OS may have to do something else) etc...
2. The test do seem to ignore if the actual OS/JVM/CPU combination offer a proper resolution up to the nanosecond.

   Even though there's a `System.nanoTime()` are you sure the JVM and the OS have the proper resolution. On windows for example, there's the JVM don't have access to the the real nanosecond, but instead to some counter, not a wall-clock time. The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) states this, here's snippet :

   > This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin time (perhaps in the future, **so values may be negative**). The same origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a Java virtual machine; other virtual machine instances are likely to use a different origin.
   >
   > This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - **no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of currentTimeMillis()**.
3. The test also ignores how Mockito works.

   Mockito **stores every invocation** in its own model in order to be able to verify these calls **after** executing the scenario. So on every iteration of the loop Mockito stores another invocation up to 2M invocations, which will impact the JVM (maybe the mock instance will hold several generations and promoted to the tenured which is definitely more costly for the GC). That means that the more the iterations the more this code stresses the JVM and not Mockito.

   I believe it's not released (there's dev binaries on jcentral however), but Mockito will offer a setting to allow mockito to stub only hence it will not store invocations, which may allow Mockito to fit well in a scenario like this one.
4. The test lacks proper statistical analysis.

   Interestingly enough the code of the test have a pseudo percentile approach. Which is good! Although it doesn't work like that and in this case it cannot work to catch the big issue. Instead it should record every measure in order to extract the tendencies of the evolution of the time mockito spent as the iteration count advances.

   And if you want, it's good idea to store every recorded measure, so it would be possible to feed them to a proper statistical analysis tool like **R** in order extract a graph, percentile data, etc.

   On that statistical matter it would certainly be interesting to use the [HDRHistogram](https://github.com/HdrHistogram/HdrHistogram). Outside a microbenchmark of course as it will impact the memory and alter the result of the microbenchmark. Let's keep that for JMH.

Both point 1 and 2 can be addressed if you change the code to use JMH.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Brice, thanks for your long answer.  I discounted warmup time, e.g. perhaps Mockito takes a long time doing initial setup on the first few invokations, same as Claas mentioned, by modifying the test to ignore the first 200,000 invokations - I still get the same result that several invokations take over a second.  I discounted (2) because the times are just too large, nanoTime() might be a little inaccurate but it isn't whole seconds out.  (4) I can kind of answer because of running the test of my real code like I mentioned in the FYI above - I can observe that it tends to run perfectly fine

Comment: and smooth for several seconds, then suddenly freeze for up to a second, then run perfectly fine and smooth for several seconds again.  So it isn't starting quickly and slowing, or starting slowly and improving, its running generally fine but with several isolated really bad lag spikes.  I can observe the same from the posted SSCCE by adding in a System.out.println(duration);  I believe (3) is the real problem... it seems to be what they're talking about here?  https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=84

Comment: Yeah I was just mentioning a few things about the JVM, I could have mentioned deoptimization too. Anyway in this case I don't think the warmup will alter the test. There's just way too much stuff the JVM can do. I again **strongly** advises you to use JMH it will avoid most pitfalls when microbenchmarking. Indeed The erratic behavior you are seeing is probably about the GC due to point 3, but that doesn't discard the fourth point ;)
And lastly the `stubOnly` stuff is in the github repo, you can try it out.

Answer (score 1):

A JVM is a very complex thing that does a lot of optimization at runtime (including caching and byte code optimization). Thus, measuring execution time of Java programs, first of all you should do a warmup phase before doing your actual benchmark.

I expect that your first four runs took your longest profilling time and afterwards, the execution time became better and better.

Execute your benchmark a few hundreds or thousands times before you actually start profiling. Afterwards, I expect your measurement results should become more stable.